# 3.7 V battery charging

Tags: battery-charging

I want to make a electronic device powered by a 3.7 V battery. And to charge the battery a 5 V charger will be used. The maximum voltage for this device is 3.7 V - 4.0 V. But when I connect a charger the device will get 5 V. How can I protect this device from over voltage?

[image]

Comment: a 'charger' will not have a 5v output. It will have whatever's needed to charge the battery. The battery will up to 4.2v when fully charged. Rethink how your device is powered.

Comment: Note that a USB "charger" (for an iPhone or simiilar device) is reallly a 5 volt power supply,  The battery charge controller is hidden inside the iPhone or other device.  The battery in the phone DOES NOT see 5 volts.

Comment: _"The maximum voltage for this deviceis 3.7V-4.0v"_ - what is this device?

Comment: @Cloudy: I changed the title from "Electronic Device". All the questions on this site are about electronic devices. I've also changed the tags to just one: "battery-charging" as that is what your question is about.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably very badly wrong about your battery.

IF it is a Li-Ion battery :-

- the *MEAN* voltage is 3.7V,
- the *ABSOLUTE MAXIMUM* voltage is 4.2V, and
- the working range is typically about 3.0 -  4.2V

*ABSOLUTE MAXIMUM

MEANS

ABSOLUTE

MAXIMUM*

**Exceeding 4.2V is a fatally bad idea.**

Applying 5V to the battery will destroy it.
You protect against 5V by **NEVER** applying it.
There are a VAST number of LiIon chargers and charger ICs available.
Using one of these is the usual approach.

You **COULD** design your own from scratch, but you need to have a very good idea of what is involved, and it seldom makes economic or other sense to do so.

Comment: Wishing everyone a favor - I have a 2s lipo battery, 7.4v. I want to run two components (a heater of 3.7V and a motor of 6V) along with this one battery. How to do it if anyone has an idea please comment

Comment: @CloudyAkash 1. Ask the different question separately 2. Comment on this question based on answers and comments.

Comment: Why 5 volts charging a 3.7 battery will destroy it?

Comment: @AntonAndreev Ideally you should ask that as a new question - it's a good question to ask. || n the case of Lithium Ion cells (which are what was being discussed ere) it's an electrochemical issue. Applying a voltage above 4.2V to a typical LiIon cell will result in metallic Lithium "plating out". This damages the cell and reduces capacity and often then leads to a "vent with flame" event - a firy noisy rapid dangerous destruction of the cell.